# How to identify a certain Qt-widget?

Tags: qt, widget

We have Qt-GUI with toolbars, menus, etc. However, only on Mac OSX we have a strange white box in the upper left. It diappears if all toobars are present. If they are hidden again no white box is present. On next application startup it is there again. I cannot identify its source. Is there a way to identify any widget by mouse over? It seems to overlay all other widgets in place, and even worse, sometimes it hides the window buttons (minimize, close, and maximize).

Screenshots:

[image: After startup without toolbars]
[image: when undocking a GLWidget, the box is in backgound and clearly visible]

Animation:

[image: Animation]

If tested this with Qt 5.4.1, 5.5.0 on OSX 10.10.4. If searched the Qt-Bug database, but nothing found. I believe its a Qt Mac issue, as Windows and Linux are not affected.

Comment: Are you sure it is a Qt widget? Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you create a widget with a parent and forget to place it inside a layout.
To find such widget, I would start with manual hiding groups of widgets to track down where the problem widget comes from.

Also you can use this code to get widget info on mouse over:

```
class WidgetTracker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WidgetTracker();

    void startTracking();
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);
}

void WidgetTracker::startTracking()
{
    QList<QWidget*> widgets = qApp->allWidgets();
    Q_FOREACH (QWidget *widget, widgets)
    {
        widget->setMouseTracking(true);
        widget->installEventFilter(this);
    }
}


bool WidgetTracker::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object->isWidgetType() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        QMouseEvent *me = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << "mouse move:" 
                 << me->globalPos() 
                 << object->metaObject()->className() 
                 << object->objectName();
    }

    return QObject::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

You should create a `WidgetTracker` object and call `WidgetTracker::startTracking` after all widgets a constructed, e.g. in a slot connected to one of your menu items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Meanwhile I assume I've identified the corresponding widget(s). I guess the toolbars we are using, cause this behavior. However, they are all added by addToolbar() command of the QMainWindow class, which puts them to Qt::ToolBarArea. Where do I need to give a layout then?

Comment: No, you don't need to have layout for a toolbar itself if it's added using `MainWindow::addToolBar`.

Comment: The thing I found out is. When I do not add any toolbar with addToolBar() cmd, nor specifying the mainWindow as reference in their construction, then the white box disappears.

Comment: Great WidgetTracker you gave me! With that I could identify, that indeed this white box does not to be an Qt-Widget, as otherwise, some debug output while hovering over it would have been produced. (Hope my conclusions are right).